# Custom number picker?

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7.1, numericupdown

Is there an easy way to make a number picker  for windows phone 7 that is similar to the timepicker control? I want go have custom ranges of 0-99 : 0-59 . 0-9. Google, bing, and msdn seem to be very vague with information on the subject.

I found an article that describes exactly what I want to do [here.](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-LoopingSelector-in-depth--Part1-Visual-structure-and-API) Now my problem is that the article is old and if I type toolkit: in my XAML code, no suggestion comes up for a loopingselector. If I go into my toolbox, right click, choose items. There are no controls for a loopingselector or infinite list selector.

The [source code](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/upload/articles/LoopingSelectorDemo_1_2.zip) also doesn't work. It gives a bunch of errors in the XAML file that I am unable to remedy.

I am kind of at a loss on what to do here.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 / c#4.0.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like this? http://blog.ningzhang.org/2008/11/numericupdown-control-in-silverlight.html

Comment: Not really. That is for windows forms and I am trying to do it for windows phone. I want to do something like this: http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-LoopingSelector-in-depth--Part1-Visual-structure-and-API

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you are using the right namespace. LoopingSelector is in  *Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives* namespace. So your **xmlns** should be something like:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```