# Timepicker control?

Tags: windows-phone-7, timepicker, windows-phone-7.1

Is there an easy way to make a number picker  for windows phone 7 that looks like a timepicker control? I want go have custom ranges of 0-99 : 0-59 . 0-9 while keeping the native windows phone look. Google, bing, and msdn seem to be very vague with information on the subject.

I found an article that describes exactly what I want to do [here.](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-LoopingSelector-in-depth--Part1-Visual-structure-and-API) My problem is that the article is old and if I type toolkit: in my XAML code, no suggestion comes up for a loopingselector. If I go into my toolbox, right click, choose items. There are no controls for a loopingselector or infinite list selector.

The [source code](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/upload/articles/LoopingSelectorDemo_1_2.zip) also doesn't work.

I am kind of at a loss on what to do here.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 / c#4.0.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210480/custom-number-picker

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to add a reference to the recent August WP7 [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) release to your project using NuGet and then add the following namespace reference to the top of your xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    ...
    xmlns:toolkitPrimitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
/>
```

You should then be able to use code like this:

```
<toolkitPrimitives:LoopingSelector ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using the right namespace. LoopingSelector is in  *Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives* namespace. So your **xmlns** should be something like:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```