# tools similar to datepicker in windows phone to pick numbers

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone app.I want a tool like date picker in windows phone for picking numbers say from 1 to 30.How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at following links:

[Custom number picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210480/custom-number-picker)

[WP7 LoopingSelector in depth | Part1: Visual structure and API](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-loopingselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api)